# Where can I find accessible bug/issue databases with complete revision history

Tags: issue-tracking, sample

I'm performing some research and analysis on bug/issue tracking databases and more specifically on how programmers and teams of programmers actually interact with them. What I'm looking for involves understanding how those databases change over time.

So what I **don't** need for example: is a database of all the bugs of some open source project as the bugs exist today. What I do need is a complete set of revision history for every issue/bug in the database. This would enable me to pick a specific datetime and say here were the list of all the issues/bugs that existed at that moment in time.

Anyway know of some publicly accessible issue/bug databases that expose this revision data?

Ideally, the revision would look something like this (shown for a single bug, with two revisions)

```
 ISSUEID  PRI  SEV  ASSIGNEDTO  MODIFIEDON      VALIDUNTIL
 1        2    2    mel         apr-1-2010:5pm  apr-1-2010:6pm
 1        2    3    steve       apr-1-2010:6pm  NULL
```

Comment: JIRA exposes related data via its [REST API](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/), I don't really know of an easier / less complicated way. If you go that way, [ASF's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/BrowseProjects.jspa#all) will be a great source for data.

Comment: What bug tracking system you this for?  Any analysis is predicated on the existence of the data source which I am assuming already exists for you.

Comment: @Karlson - It doesn't matter what bug tracking system this is. I've just looking for any large sample set of data from somewhere that I can analyze.

Comment: @namenlos Reading your question again I am puzzled.  Are you looking for someone to publicly expose the raw data on their bug tracking to the public?  You might have to register for quite a few of them and see what you can do in terms of reports.  That might give you what you need.  Start with Bugzilla implementations on http://www.launchpad.net

Comment: What you probably need to to do is to _extract_ the data from a bug tracking system (possible with both Jira and Bugzilla). Look at any ASF or JBoss Jira or Bugzilla project.

Comment: When using TFS, you can already attach check-ins/commits to a certain workitem (bug, story, etc.). Seems to me you are looking for such a thing. Perhaps writing a plugin so you can access this information easily via a service. I don't know if TFS already has a service like though. I suspect so, as you can extend it in multiple ways. I suspect Kiln + FogBugz also has this integration setup, but I'm not sure on that. It could be I'm misunderstanding your question..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at Philip Guo's publications (and maybe get into contact). If I remember correctly, he published a few papers for which he had access to data of big bug trackers.
http://www.pgbovine.net/academic.htm#pubs